# Binary is never build

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I can't get the following code to run:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There are no compile errors.
The build output:

```
18:18:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project First Project ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-Ic:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.8.1\\include\\c++" "-Ic:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.8.1\\include\\c++\\mingw32" "-Ic:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.8.1\\include\\c++\\backward" "-Ic:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.8.1\\include" "-Ic:\\mingw\\include" "-Ic:\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.8.1\\include-fixed" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Hello.o "..\\Hello.cpp" 

18:18:58 Build Finished (took 166ms)
```

I get the dreaded "Launch failed. Binary not found." dialog. I've been over google for hours now, but nothing works.
In my project folder, a debug or release folder are created (depending on what I set it to) but it's always empty. No 'binaries' folder is created, as some posts mentioned it should.
No proposed solution worked, and disabling the antivirus didn't solve it.
How do I fix this? Thank you.

EDIT
Eclipse Version Kepler Severive Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
CDT Version: 8.3.0.201402142303

I'm using MinGW

EDIT2
Changing the "current builder" in properties>c/c++ build>tool chain editor from CDT internal builder to Gnu Make Builder does generate a makefile.
Output:
        13:57:41 **** Auto Build of configuration Debug for project First Project ****
        make all 
        Building file: ../Hello.cpp
        Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
        g++ -I"c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++" -                                I"c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\mingw32" -        I"c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\backward" -I"c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include" -I"c:\mingw\include" -I"c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include-fixed" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Hello.d" -MT"Hello.d" -o "Hello.o" "../Hello.cpp"
make: *** [Hello.o] Error 1

13:57:42 Build Finished (took 881ms)

Comment: Looks like you are only compiling, not linking.

Comment: You are only compiling the source. There is no link stage in the log.

Comment: In the Project Explorer view under Debug or Release, do you see an auto-generated "makefile"?  Could you post that also?  What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: "I'm using MinGW" - there's your real problem.

Comment: I changed the "current builder" in properties>c/c++ build>tool chain editor from CDT internal builder to Gnu Make Builder, and now it does generate "makefile", as well as objects.mk, sources.mk and subdir.mk.

Should I post the contents of the makefile?

Comment: @Daniel Kamil kozar I was just following the getting started guide, if the problem is actually MinGW, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Which compiler are you using? It appears that you are only compiling your code, not linking it too. You must build and link in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `-c` flag only compiles the source file. It doesn't link with the object file into an executable. Add this:

```
g++ -o "..\\Hello.exe" "..\\Hello.o" && "..\\Hello.exe"
```

Comment: the `-o` flag is used to name the output file. It has nothing to do with compiling versus linking. The reason your command links is because you're not passing the `-c` flag. You can also compile and link using a command like: `g++ Hello.cpp`.

Comment: Where should I add that then? I was using the buttons on the toolbar to build and run. Shouldn't it link automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `-c` flag from your compile line and change `-o Hello.o` to `-o Hello.exe` (guess you use Windows).